# How to add JComboBox(Object[] items) to jComboBox1.addItem(String items);

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

```
Object[] items = {new ComboItem("A"), new ComboItem("B"),
            new ComboItem("1", false), new ComboItem("2", false),
            new ComboItem("abc"), new ComboItem("def")};
```

as Above, I have created a Object Array of items to be put inside a `jComboBox1` component **(Which I have been dragged and dropped into my `JFrame`)**
But I cannot normally add this **items** (e.i Object[] items) into my `jComboBox1`

But I can do it like this: **(But this is not what I want)**

```
JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(items);
```

**I don't want to do this by creating a new `JComboBox` object** I want to add it into my Dragged and Dropped `jComboBox1`

can you anyone give any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
jComboBox1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(items));
```

Comment: Thank you Very much! It really helped!

Answer (score 0):

Initiate the JComboBox with array of Items. Whenever you want modify items in combobox add/remove the item from the array and do a repaint after the change.

Comment: Read the Question carefully. This does not answer my question Sir

Comment: oops!... so in your case combobox is already instantiated and you want modify items in the combo box. right?

Comment: There is a method called setModel and getModel for JComboBox, we usually use this to set items.. did you try that one?

Comment: Not yet :) I will try that. Yes Sir :)  I have already instantiated combobox and I want modify items in the combo box as you said :)